# Regex for getting URL-compatible directory?

Tags: php, regex

I have an internal link system on my site, and I currently use this to detect text after a markup:

`'/__IL__(.+)/'`

The problem with this is that it picks up characters like "<", meaning if someone uses a line break, the result will be this:

`http://www.[sitename].org/[user's url] <br/>`

What would be a better regex expression for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instructing your regular expression to include all characters BUT the character that begins an HTML tag:

`'/__IL__([^<]+)/'`